# Asus eeePC - Screen Brightness Issue

Tags: 12.04, brightness, asus, ubuntu-netbook, eeepc

I have ASUS 1015CX Netbook on which I have installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS. All seem to work fine however there is an issue with brightness settings; changing the brightness (both through settings and with hotkeys) has no effect.

However once I log off or power down the screen brightness drops to minimal level. I have to log in and out again for the brightness to increase.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add the outputs of `ls /sys/class/backlight` and `cat /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` to the question. have you installed the proprietary CedarView driver? [ASUS 1015CX specs](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/Eee_PC_1015CX/#specifications).

Comment: @mikewhatever

`ls /sys/class/backlight`:

`acpi_video0  psb-bl`

`cat/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`:

`9`
`100`

Comment: No I did not install the CedarView driver. Where can I get this?

Comment: You can get it from the Additional Drivers, with three pre-conditions: 32bit OS, 3.2 kernel and 1.11 xorg version.

Comment: Nothing appears in the Additional Drivers section, is there a way to get it manually then?

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly convenient, but when this happens to me, I run:

```
sudo pm-suspend
```

And then wake the machine again.  It comes back with full brightness!

That might be preferable to logging out and in again.  ;)